# java singleton with windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, singleton

I am using version 1.5.0_22 Java on Windows 7 32bit and I identified in my application to the singleton object reference does not keep the memory of one process to another, even running in the same JVM.

Has anyone had this problem or know how to solve it?

thank you

Comment: "does not keep the memory of one process to another" <-- I do not understand that :( Anyway, example code of your singleton implementation and usage? Also, unless this problem is *specific* to Windows 7, consider removing it from the title/tags... and consider Java 6 (or 7 even).

Comment: What do you mean by "not keep the memory of one process to another"?

Comment: I don't understand - the singleton doesn't keep the same memory reference between separate runnings of the program? Why would it? When you close the app, all memory (and their pointers/memory references) are released.

Comment: @normalocity ...but that is followed up with "evening running in the same JVM". I'm confused :)

Comment: Sample code is probably the only thing that will clear this up.

Comment: Shoot in the dark: you need `java.util.prefs.Preferences`.

Answer (score 0):

There is always one Singleton per one JVM. If you are running more threads in your application, they share the same instance of the Singleton. 
If not, then show us your code and how are you using your singleton.

If you are running Java Swing application (or something like that) I doubt that there are more than one instance of your Singleton.

If you are running that in servlet environment... yes, you could have more instances. If that is the case, get rid of Singleton pattern (you should find out other solution).

Still not sure? Please read this: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/singletons/

Comment: You mean one Singleton per class loader